# No me detecta la suma del contador

Tags: c#

EL usuario ingresa una contraseña y este debe contener al menos 2 números y si no los contiene  no puede avanzar el programa, en un ciclo comparo los valores de la entrada del usuario y los números de un arreglo pero al añadir los 2 valores necesarios me sigue saliendo el mensaje

```
  string s = txtUsuario.Text;
        char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
        int contador = 0;
        int[] valores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
        string cadena = "";


        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chars.Length; ctr++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (chars[ctr] == valores[i])
                    {
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                cadena += string.Format("{0}: {1}", ctr, chars[ctr]) + "\n";
            }
        if (contador < 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar 2 numeros");
            return;
        }
        else
            richTextBox1.Text = cadena;
```

Comment: ¿Tienes que hacerlo con arrays? porque con una expresión regular puedes hacer  la validación.

Comment: Hola, no lo ocupo hacer con arrays, no lo podía hacer y se me ocurrió hacerlo de esta manera

Comment: Te puse la alternativa como respuesta.

Comment: Actualicé la expresión regular de  @"\d+"  a @"\d"  puesto que con la primero  si ponen los numeros contiguos los toma como 1 solo numero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una alternativa a tu solución es utilizar una expresión regular como te pongo en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
    string password = "MiPassword";

    if(Regex.Matches(password,@"\d",RegexOptions.Singleline).Count<2){
         MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar 2 numeros");
         return;
    }
```

En el ejemplo, *password* es invalido, mientras no tenga 2 numeros.

Me olvidaba, requiere:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda